# specifying indices using if-else

Tags: python, arrays, list, slice

I have a code that goes like this:

```
if self.modality == "A": 
    idx = 0
elif self.modality == "B": 
    idx = 1
elif self.modality == "C": 
    idx = 2
elif self.modality == "D": 
    idx = 3
elif self.modality == "all": 
    idx = 0:5

my_value = get_value(my_array[idx])
```

My problem  is for different values of `self.modality`, I would like specific different indices from  `my_array`. when `self.modality== "all"` , I would like to specific ranges of values.

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python a common way to map from one set of values to another is using a dict. Also note that dict values can be any Python entity, such as a tuple representing a `(low, high)` range, or even a class to instantiate!

So if you want to map some text strings to some ranges you would code something like

```
low,high = {
   "A":(0,1), "B":(1,2), "C":(2,3), "D":(3,4), "all":(0,5) 
    } [self.modality]

my_value = get_value( my_array[low:high] )
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is almost there, you can reference *lists* by indices such as: `my_array[idx]`.

So...

```
def modality_check(self):
    if self.modality == "A":
        return my_array[0]
    elif self.modality == "B":
        return my_array[1]
    ...
    ...
    ...
    elif self.modality = "All":
        return my_array[2:5]
```